# Windows Server 2012 - alert on low disk space

Tags: windows-server-2012, health-monitoring

How can I configure to receive an email on low disk space? I'm using Windows Server 2012 and after Googling for a while I couldn't find a way to do something that should be really simple.

Comment: Windows Server Essencials is included in Windows Server 2012? I'm sorry to ask this but I'm a developer trying to manage a server.

Comment: Sorry that previous comment will not work out. Easiest way I can think of without monitoring software is powershell in a scheduled task. This link has an example powershell script for retrieving disk space. All you need to do is add logic for conditional email out. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/powershell/129889/